# Dual boot with HDD and SSD

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, hard-drive, boot, ssd

On my desktop PC I've got an HDD with Windows 7 and Ubuntu. Ubuntu was installed second after Windows 7, and GRUB lets me choose between the two OSs.

A short time ago, I bought an SSD. I installed Windows 7 and updated it to Windows 10. I didn't unplug the HDD, so when the disk boots, the boot menu gives me the options to choose either Windows 10 or Windows 7 and Ubuntu is gone.

I decided to get my Ubuntu back by using the Live CD and the boot-recover tool. For doing this, I unplugged the SSD first. Now have my Ubuntu and the grub again, but if I unplug the SSD again,it says:

```
Disk boot failure insert system disk and press enter.
```

I did not lose Windows 10, but I can only access it through the HDD. In other words, the computer boots Linux GRUB (I have to choose between Ubuntu and Windows 7), if I choose Windows 7 then Windows 10 boot asks me to choose between Windows 10 or Windows 7.

I want to boot again from the SSD with only Windows 10, and let the HDD with Windows 7 and Ubuntu. How can I do that? I made a Recovery USB from Windows 10, but I don't know if it will work. The problems I've read were between two OS only, or one disk, so I'm not so sure how to achieve what I want.